# AUCTeX cannot find a working TeX distribution

Tags: latex, auctex

I tried to compile, this error message appears.

ERROR: AUCTeX cannot find a working TeX distribution.
Make sure you have one and that TeX binaries are in PATH environment variable

I have installed texlive 2016 manually and installed emacs by package.
and added texlive to .bashrc. so directory of texlive shown in emacs shell by typing echo $PATH.
My OS is ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Not sure this will work, but try setting the PATH in `.profile` rather than in `.bashrc`.

Comment: See if emacs knows the correct path: evaluate `(getenv "PATH")`. If you are starting emacs from a desktop environment, it will not know it if you just added it to the path in `.bashrc`. Adding it to `.profile` per the previous comment might work. If that does not work, start an xterm running bash (which will source `.bashrc`) and start emacs from the command line: that should work. You can then worry about how to tell your desktop environment to DTRT.

Comment: @Nick can you make than a answer - I couldn't find a good duplicate on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Comment promoted to an answer at the request of Andrew Swann.]

See if emacs knows the correct path: evaluate `(getenv "PATH")`. If you are starting emacs from a desktop environment, it will not know it if you just added it to the path in `.bashrc`. Adding it to `.profile` per the previous comment might work. If that does not work, start an xterm running bash (which will source `.bashrc`) and start emacs from the command line: that should work. You can then worry about how to tell your desktop environment to DTRT.